# Is there a maximum amount of reputation one can earn from an answer?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, answers, reputation

Just noticed that I got a couple of upvotes on my "[torture](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4498/does-torture-work-well-as-an-interrogation-technique/4500#4500)" answer, but no points were awarded.  Is there a maximum number of points you can get over the life of an answer (or question)?  Just found it curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was made community-wiki by being edited 10 times, I've removed the community wiki status from the post again.

Comment: Ah, okay!  I didn't realize that, I was just seeing activity on the answer and wondered what was up.